# Substitution of root beer concentrate for extract

Tags: baking, substitutions, extracts

I'd like to make [these root beer float cupcakes](http://www.bhg.com/recipe/layer-cakes/root-beer-float-cupcakes/). The recipe calls for root beer extract, but I haven't found any locally, and the cost plus shipping on Amazon is a little more than I'd like. I've tried googling this, but haven't come up with a definitive answer: can I substitute root beer **concentrate** (easily bought locally)? If so, what adjustments have to be made?

Answer (score 1):

Usually extracts are used for flavoring foods, but in this case root beer extracts and concentrates both are for making root beer at home, so I would suspect that you could use concentrate in this case as long as you get the proportions right and use a non-sweetened concentrate. The products out there vary in concentration and sugar content, you'll probably have to buy one and experiment to get the amounts right.